# Pre-train neural networks in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm training a deep neural network. Training directly the full network is difficult, therefore, I prefer to train layer by layer. Firstly, I train a network with a single hidden layer. After that, I save the model using `tf.train.Saver`. Next time, I restore variables by calling:

```
saver.restore(sess, "runs/simple-model.ckpt")
```

Of course, this time, the architecture has changed because I insert a new layer between the hidden layer and the output layer, and a new variable is used. For this reason, Tensorflow throws an error: `Key not found`

My question is that: How to train neural network layer by layer in Tensorflow? I want to do it before final fine-tuning of the full network.
Many thanks.

Comment: `saver` constructor accepts lists of variables to initialize. So you can specify existing variables for saver, and initialize new variables manually

Comment: yes, but it seems that Tensorflow claims that new variable doesn't exist in the old graph. I feel like Saver always requires the same architecture.

Comment: You can double-check that this variable exists in the graph by looking at the graph (`tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the entire network with shared weights.
Instead of training over all the layers define a function that runs just the layers that you want and finally save the entire network.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I come to a simple solution. In Python, a numpy array can be saved easily by using `numpy.save`. After that, we can load the array by: `numpy.load`. Therefore, after training, I can evaluate the variable using `var.eval()` to convert it to a numpy array, then save it.